# Facebook post with an external link to PHP script and be able to leverage Facebook data in that script

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have been looking around for an answer to this but is it possible to 
Create a Facebook post containing an external link to a PHP script and have the Facebook user data for the customer who clicked available to the script. Essentially can you POST out of Facebook the customer's data on an action like a click?

Comment: At best, you can get the URL that the user was on when he clicked.  It's easily spoofable, but if you assume he clicked from facebook, then that URL might have some identifying information.  Try `echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, only seeing this now. For some reason, i never saw the notification. You can actually achieve this by creating an App. The dataset is available if the user accepts your app.